# How much is it/are they?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

How should I ask about the cost of my purchase if it consists of several items, e.g. one melon, three apples and some grapes?
I would ask "How much is it?" meaning that my purchase is the whole thing. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct and understandable, it just depends how you want to ask

> How much is it?
>   *how much is the total*
>
> How much are they *(altogether)*?
>   *how much are the items all together*

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> - *"how much **is it**?"* 
>     The total amount/the bill; a singular noun (a book), an uncountable noun.
> - *"how much **are they**?"* 
>     All the products; plural